# Trying to identify a UK series 1970s/1980s featuring an underground stone circle

Tags: story-identification

For a long time I've been trying to identify a show I watched as a child in New Zealand around about 1982. I was only 7 at the time, so please forgive vagueness...

Features I remember:

- It was UK-made, either from mid to late 1970s or early 80s
- It featured an underground archaeological excavation, with plenty of people wearing helmets and lamps.
- It involved a scene with people standing in a circle of stones - one person in front of each stone, I think each one associated with signs of the zodiac, or tarot symbols, or pagan gods?

I can confirm it's not the following:

- Children of the Stones - I've seen this show (and highly recommend it) but watching it nearly 30 years later did not trigger any recognition. There is a lot of similarity though, so I concede my memory might be of this but totally warped...
- Quatermass and the Pit - the feel of the show was similar to Quatermass (again, highly recommended), but my one was in colour.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that what you remember was called "Raven".  I saw it in the UK sometime around 1980.  All I recall is lots of caves, and signs of the zodiac.  There was some kind of underground control room, with lots of closed circuit TVs in it.  It fits your description.

There is a wikipedia page for the series I'm talking about here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_(1977_TV_series).  It doesn't have much information though.

There was also a book written based on the story (see here at [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?299147)).  [image: The cover of the book]

Comment: Some more info on the series in the [review of the British DVD](http://www.horrorview.com/movie-reviews/raven-the-complete-series), it says the main character "becomes involved in the excavations of a nearby cave system where carved symbols and ancient artifacts have been found all of which seem to bear out the Professor's theory that the myth of King Arthur was based in historical truth, and that the site (near a circle of ancient stones) was once a sacred place", and though the review is positive it says "The rather large role that astrology plays in the plot dates the production somewhat".

Comment: Yeah sounds about right. I'd forgotten the King Arthur aspect. I thought it couldn't make sense with stone circles and zodiac signs as well! Amusing to see Phil Daniels of "Parklife!" fame as the lead. Thanks!